# Explain this strange effect from the order of arguments (and provide a workaround, if possible)

Tags: agda

While trying to come up with a solution to a question I posed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31900036/proof-help-in-agda-node-balancing-in-data-avl), I discovered that the acceptability (by Agda) of a refl proof depends in a strange way on the order of arguments of a function that is called on one side of the equation.

In code below, see how all but one of the bottom 4 theorems are proved with refl. It's important to note that `join` and `join'` differ only in the order of arguments. Correspondingly, I would think that the `thm`s that invoke them should be proved equivalently, but apparently that is not so.

Why the discrepancy? Does this represent a bug in Agda? How would I prove the remaining theorem (`thm1`)?

```
open import Data.Nat
open import Data.Product

-- Stolen (with little modification) from Data.AVL

data ℕ₂ : Set where
  0# : ℕ₂
  1# : ℕ₂

infixl 6 _⊕_

_⊕_ : ℕ₂ → ℕ → ℕ
0# ⊕ n = n
1# ⊕ n = suc n

infix 4 _∼_⊔_

data _∼_⊔_ : ℕ → ℕ → ℕ → Set where
  ∼+ : ∀ {n} →     n ∼ suc n ⊔ suc n
  ∼0 : ∀ {n} →     n ∼ n     ⊔ n
  ∼- : ∀ {n} → suc n ∼ n     ⊔ suc n

max∼ : ∀ {i j m} → i ∼ j ⊔ m → m ∼ i ⊔ m
max∼ ∼+ = ∼-
max∼ ∼0 = ∼0
max∼ ∼- = ∼0

∼max : ∀ {i j m} → i ∼ j ⊔ m → j ∼ m ⊔ m
∼max ∼+ = ∼0
∼max ∼0 = ∼0
∼max ∼- = ∼+

-- for simplicity, this tree has no keys
data Tree : ℕ → Set where
  leaf : Tree 0
  node : ∀ {l u h}
         (L : Tree l)
         (U : Tree u)
         (bal : l ∼ u ⊔ h) →
         Tree (suc h)

-- similar to joinˡ⁺ from Data.AVL

join : ∀ {hˡ hʳ h : ℕ} →
       (∃ λ i → Tree (i ⊕ hˡ)) →
       Tree hʳ →
       (bal : hˡ ∼ hʳ ⊔ h) →
       ∃ λ i → Tree (i ⊕ (suc h))
join (1# , node t₁
                (node t₃ t₅ bal)
                ∼+) t₇ ∼-  = (0# , node 
                                        (node t₁ t₃ (max∼ bal))
                                        (node t₅ t₇ (∼max bal))
                                        ∼0)
join (1# , node t₁ t₃ ∼-) t₅ ∼-  = (0# , node t₁ (node t₃ t₅ ∼0) ∼0)
join (1# , node t₁ t₃ ∼0) t₅ ∼-  = (1# , node t₁ (node t₃ t₅ ∼-) ∼+)
join (1# , t₁)            t₃ ∼0  = (1# , node t₁ t₃ ∼-)
join (1# , t₁)            t₃ ∼+  = (0# , node t₁ t₃ ∼0)
join (0# , t₁)            t₃ bal = (0# , node t₁ t₃ bal)

-- just like join but with "bal" earlier in the argument list
join' : ∀ {hˡ hʳ h : ℕ} →
       (bal : hˡ ∼ hʳ ⊔ h) →
       (∃ λ i → Tree (i ⊕ hˡ)) →
       Tree hʳ →
       ∃ λ i → Tree (i ⊕ (suc h))
join' ∼- (1# , node t₁
                (node t₃ t₅ bal)
                ∼+) t₇  = (0# , node 
                                        (node t₁ t₃ (max∼ bal))
                                        (node t₅ t₇ (∼max bal))
                                        ∼0)
join' ∼-  (1# , node t₁ t₃ ∼-) t₅ = (0# , node t₁ (node t₃ t₅ ∼0) ∼0)
join' ∼-  (1# , node t₁ t₃ ∼0) t₅ = (1# , node t₁ (node t₃ t₅ ∼-) ∼+)
join' ∼0  (1# , t₁)            t₃ = (1# , node t₁ t₃ ∼-)
join' ∼+  (1# , t₁)            t₃ = (0# , node t₁ t₃ ∼0)
join' bal (0# , t₁)            t₃ = (0# , node t₁ t₃ bal)

open import Relation.Binary.PropositionalEquality

thm0  : ∀ {h : ℕ} (tl : Tree      h ) (tr : Tree (suc h)) → join (0# , tl) tr ∼+ ≡ (0# , node tl tr ∼+)
thm0 tl tr = refl

thm1  : ∀ {h : ℕ} (tl : Tree (suc h)) (tr : Tree (suc h)) → join (1# , tl) tr ∼+ ≡ (0# , node tl tr ∼0)
thm1 tl tr = {!!} -- FIXME refl doesn't work here!

thm0' : ∀ {h : ℕ} (tl : Tree      h ) (tr : Tree (suc h)) → join' ∼+ (0# , tl) tr ≡ (0# , node tl tr ∼+)
thm0' tl tr = refl

thm1' : ∀ {h : ℕ} (tl : Tree (suc h)) (tr : Tree (suc h)) → join' ∼+ (1# , tl) tr ≡ (0# , node tl tr ∼0)
thm1' tl tr = refl -- refl works fine here, and all I did was switch the order of arguments to join(')
```

If I try to prove `thm1` with refl, I get the following error:

```
proj₁ (join (1# , tl) tr ∼+) != 0# of type ℕ₂
when checking that the expression refl has type
join (1# , tl) tr ∼+ ≡ (0# , node tl tr ∼0)
```

NB: This is using Agda 2.4.2.3 and the stdlib of the same version (pulled from github [here](https://github.com/agda/agda-stdlib/tree/2.4.2.3).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write

```
thm1  : ∀ {h : ℕ} (tl : Tree (suc h)) (tr : Tree (suc h)) → join (1# , tl) tr ∼+ ≡ (0# , node tl tr ∼0)
thm1 (node tl (node tl₁ tl₂ bal) ∼+) tr = refl
thm1 (node tl  leaf              ∼0) tr = refl
thm1 (node tl (node tl₁ tl₂ bal) ∼0) tr = refl
thm1 (node tl  leaf              ∼-) tr = refl
thm1 (node tl (node tl₁ tl₂ bal) ∼-) tr = refl
```

In `thm1` Agda forces the first argument (`tl`) to be in WHNF, even if the clause can be determined by looking at the third argument of `join` and then at the first.

Comment: How did you know to case-split the first argument, the second and third arguments of the first argument, but not bother splitting the first argument of the first argument nor the second argument? Was that just trial and error?

Comment: Ahh, I see. It's from the structure (left hand side) of the definition of `join`.

Comment: @m0davis, that's because of how pattern matching used in the first clause of `join`: `join (1# , node t₁ (node t₃ t₅ bal) ∼+) t₇ = ...`. Here `node` and `~+` are constructors, so to make `join (1# , tl) tr ∼+` reducible you need to split on `tl` such that there will be constructors at the same positions. Then Agda is able to proceed.

Comment: Via Jacques Carette (on the agda mailing list): "You will find an (operational) explanation at the bottom of
http://wiki.portal.chalmers.se/agda/pmwiki.php?n=ReferenceManual.PatternMatching. So order of arguments (and order of clauses) matter, because of the semantics in terms of case trees."

Comment: @m0davis, yep, I forgot, that Agda's pattern matching is not only top-down, but also left-to-right, so Agda doesn't try to unify `∼+` with `∼-` and `∼0` and hence doesn't proceed further.